# Weird, occasional, WiFi connection issue on an HP laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I encountering this weird, occasional, WiFi connection problem:

In middle of the usage of laptop, WiFi connection goes offline
then if I connect it again, it says:

> “Can't connect to this network.”

[image: Screenshot.]

Then I turned on and off “Airport Zone,” then all existing
wifi connections are gone:

[image: Screenshot.]

If I restart the laptop, then all wifi connections are back.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Somebody fix my image links.

Answer (score 0):

Analyze the situation:
Use your smartphone and Download
[wifi Analyzer on google play, Andoroid apps](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer)

With it you can check whether any of your neighbors have e.g. equal strength or stronger AP's, maybe even running on the same channel as your AP.

A temporary high usage on one of them might be the explanation / culprit here.